# Logstash/Gelf not stored all MDCs

Tags: java, json, jakarta-ee, logstash, mdc

I'm using [Logstash/Gelf](https://logging.paluch.biz) as a log-tools in my application. I follow [this sample](https://logging.paluch.biz/examples/wildfly-json.html) for setting up my logger as `JSON` file. here is my wildfly config (`standalone.xml`):

```
<profile>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:3.0">
        <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="JsonLog" autoflush="true">
            <level name="ALL"/>
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="JsonFormatter"/>
            </formatter>
            <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.json"/>
            <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
            <append value="true"/>
        </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
        ...
        <logger category="org.somepackgs.SoapLogHandler" use-parent-handlers="true">
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="JsonLog"/>
            </handlers>
        </logger>
        ...
        <formatter name="JsonFormatter">
            <custom-formatter module="biz.paluch.logging" class="biz.paluch.logging.gelf.wildfly.WildFlyJsonFormatter">
                <properties>
                    <property name="version" value="1.0"/>
                    <property name="facility" value="java-test"/>
                    <property name="fields" value="Time,Severity"/>
                    <property name="extractStackTrace" value="true"/>
                    <property name="filterStackTrace" value="true"/>
                    <property name="includeLogMessageParameters" value="true"/>
                    <property name="includeLocation" value="true"/>
                    <property name="mdcProfiling" value="true"/>
                    <property name="timestampPattern" value="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS"/>
                    <property name="mdcFields" value="requestId"/>
                    <property name="dynamicMdcFields" value="mdc.*,(mdc|MDC)fields"/>
                    <property name="includeFullMdc" value="true"/>
                </properties>
            </custom-formatter>
        </formatter>
    </subsystem>
</profile>
```

In `SoapLogHandler` I put some fields in `MDC`, my application has a`GeneralInterceptor` for checking some business logic and I want log some extra fields (like result, duration time) after process request:

```
@AroundInvoke
public Object run(InvocationContext ictx) throws Exception {
    MDC.put("requestId", UUID.randomUUID());
    try{
        //other codes & business checks...
        obj = ictx.proceed();
     } catch (Exception ex) {

    } finally {
        logAfterInvokation(ictx);
    }
}
```

in `logAfterInvokation` method, I put some extra fields (like result, duration time) in `MDC`; But when line `obj = ictx.proceed();` runs, Logstash automatically store some fields in `server.json` file and my extra fields never adds to this file, here is one node of my `server.json` file:

```
{
    "short_message": "short message text...",
    "full_message": "full message text...",
    "timestamp": "1558244976.376",
    "level": "6",
    "facility": "java-test",
    "logType": "entry",
    "LoggerName": "org.somepackgs.SoapLogHandler",
    "fieldName1": "fieldValue1",
    "destination": "destination1",
    "Time": "2019-05-19 10:19:36,376",
    "Severity": "INFO",
    "source": "my-App",
    "Thread": "default task-1",
    "SourceMethodName": "logMessage",
    "SourceSimpleClassName": "SoapLogHandler",
    "requestId": "d4d8482f-e9ae-4f31-acce-1629515a2ffd",
    "SourceClassName": "org.somepackgs.SoapLogHandler"
}
```

So why Logstash not store all of `MDC` contents? or How I can store all of my `MDC` contents to json file? Any help would be appreciated!

**Updated:** I think my `JsonLog` (in `standalone.xml`) placed in wrong location, Becuase It logs `org.somepackgs.SoapLogHandler` and the main application's flow occurs in `interceptor`, but when I place `JsonLog` for `org.somepackgs.GeneralInterceptor`, the SOAP-XML not logged anymore.

Comment: can you add the field names which you add in `mdc` or the code as to how you add those?

Comment: I put in MDC in regular way: `MDC.put("methodName", ictx.getMethod().getName());`

Comment: That should not work right because `<property name="dynamicMdcFields" value="mdc.*,(mdc|MDC)fields"/>` the regex will fail

Comment: `org.somepackgs.SoapLogHandler` This is the log implementation class right? It should not have to do anything with where you add things to MDC. Can you test my updating the regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I placed my JsonLog (in `standalone.xml`) in wrong location, Becuase all of `MDC`s is not initialized when `org.somepackgs.SoapLogHandler` runs, So I need create a class with name `FinalLogger` and call one method of this class for logging after `obj = ictx.proceed();` line, something like below:

```
FinalLogger.logInfo("some text.");
```

and `FinalLogger` is like below:

```
package org.somepackgs;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class FinalLogger {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(FinalLogger.class);

    public static void logInfo(String message) {
        logger.info(message);
    }
}
```

and in `standalone.xml` put jsonLog on `FinalLogger`:

```
<logger category="org.somepackgs.FinalLogger" use-parent-handlers="true">
    <level name="INFO"/>
    <handlers>
        <handler name="JsonLog"/>
    </handlers>
</logger>
```

Because the `FinalLogger` call at end of every rquest, So in time of running this all `MDC`s has been initialized and at this time stored in json log file.

Answer (score 0):

```
<property name="dynamicMdcFields" value="mdc.*,(mdc|MDC)fields"/>
```

The **dynamicMdcFields** evaluates every value you put through a regex that you provide in its **value**.
Probably, you need to update your **regex** or update field names that you put in **MDC**

Comment: yes, you either need to change the value to `[a-zA-Z0-9]*` or update `MDC.put("methodName", ictx.getMethod().getName());` to `MDC.put("mdc.methodName", ictx.getMethod().getName());`

Comment: I changed  that line as `<property name="dynamicMdcFields" value="[a-zA-Z0-9]*"/>` but in json file nothings changed, it won't work. In any case, thank you in advance!

Comment: what is the output of `ictx.getMethod().getName()` ?

Comment: `ictx` is `InvocationContext` default argument of Interceptor, `ictx.getMethod().getName()` returns method's name (in `String`) that Interceptor invoke during call this method.